# JQuery - Galeria de Fotos por CATEGORIA

Tags: jquery, css

Estou trabalhando com um template bootstrap chamado CORLATE. Na Galeria de Fotos, preciso tirar aquela opção todos- All e deixar somente as categorias. O problema é que quando carrega a página, mesmo tirando o All ele puxa novamente todas as imagens, e no caso precisaria ficar direto nos ítens da primeira categoria.

https://www.themezy.com/free-website-templates/185-corlate-free-responsive-bootstrap-template

Alguém pode me ajudar? Please!!! Anexo seguem os códigos e acima o link do template completo.

```js
jQuery(function($) {'use strict',

 //#main-slider
 $(function(){
  $('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({
   interval: 8000
  });
 });


 // accordian
 $('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('.panel-group').children().each(function(){
  $(this).find('>.panel-heading').removeClass('active');
   });

   $(this).closest('.panel-heading').toggleClass('active');
 });

 //Initiat WOW JS
 new WOW().init();

 // portfolio filter
 $(window).load(function(){'use strict';
  var $portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter >li>a');
  var $portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');
  $portfolio.isotope({
   itemSelector : '.portfolio-item',
   layoutMode : 'fitRows'
  });
  
  $portfolio_selectors.on('click', function(){
   $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
   $portfolio.isotope({ filter: selector });
   return false;
  });
 });

 // Contact form
 var form = $('#main-contact-form');
 form.submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
  $.ajax({
   url: $(this).attr('action'),

   beforeSend: function(){
    form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
   }
  }).done(function(data){
   form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
  });
 });

 
 //goto top
 $('.gototop').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("body").offset().top
  }, 500);
 }); 

 //Pretty Photo
 $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
  social_tools: false
 }); 
});
```

```css
/*************************
********* Portfolio CSS ******
**************************/

#portfolio_page {
  margin-top: 115px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.portfolio-items, 
.portfolio-filter {
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.portfolio-filter > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.portfolio-filter > li a {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 0.9s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.9s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.9s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.9s ease 0s;
  border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.portfolio-filter > li a:hover,
.portfolio-filter > li a.active{
  color:#fff;
  background: #c52d2f;
  border: 1px solid #c52d2f;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

.portfolio-items > li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.portfolio-item {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

/* Start: Recommended Isotope styles */
/**** Isotope Filtering ****/
.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}

.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

/**** Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope {
  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
  -moz-transition-property: height, width;
  -ms-transition-property: height, width;
  -o-transition-property: height, width;
  transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
  -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
  -o-transition-property: -o-transform, opacity;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
}

/**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
.isotope.no-transition,
.isotope.no-transition .isotope-item,
.isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0s;
}

/* End: Recommended Isotope styles */
/* disable CSS transitions for containers with infinite scrolling*/
.isotope.infinite-scrolling {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -ms-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
title = "Portfolio"
url = "/portfolio"
layout = "default"
==
    <section id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="center">
               <h2>Portfolio</h2>
               <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut <br> et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
            </div>
        

            <ul class="portfolio-filter text-center">
                <li><a class="btn btn-default active" href="#" data-filter="*">All Works</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".bootstrap">Creative</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".html">Photography</a></li>
                <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".wordpress">Web Development</a></li>
            </ul><!--/#portfolio-filter-->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="portfolio-items">
                    <div class="portfolio-item apps col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="recent-work-wrap">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/recent/item1.png'|theme }}" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="recent-work-inner">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Business theme</a></h3>
                                    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority</p>
                                    <a class="preview" href="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/full/item1.png'|theme }}" rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/.portfolio-item-->

                    <div class="portfolio-item joomla bootstrap col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="recent-work-wrap">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/recent/item2.png'|theme }}" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="recent-work-inner">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Business theme</a></h3>
                                    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority</p>
                                    <a class="preview" href="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/full/item2.png'|theme }}" rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>          
                    </div><!--/.portfolio-item-->

                    <div class="portfolio-item bootstrap wordpress col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="recent-work-wrap">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/recent/item3.png'|theme }}" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="recent-work-inner">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Business theme</a></h3>
                                    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority</p>
                                    <a class="preview" href="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/full/item3.png'|theme }}" rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>        
                    </div><!--/.portfolio-item-->

                    <div class="portfolio-item joomla wordpress apps col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="recent-work-wrap">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/recent/item4.png'|theme }}" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="recent-work-inner">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Business theme</a></h3>
                                    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority</p>
                                    <a class="preview" href="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/full/item4.png'|theme }}" rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>           
                    </div><!--/.portfolio-item-->
          
                    <div class="portfolio-item joomla html bootstrap col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="recent-work-wrap">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/recent/item5.png'|theme }}" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="recent-work-inner">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Business theme</a></h3>
                                    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority</p>
                                    <a class="preview" href="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/full/item5.png'|theme }}" rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>      
                    </div><!--/.portfolio-item-->

                    <div class="portfolio-item wordpress html apps col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="recent-work-wrap">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/recent/item6.png'|theme }}" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="recent-work-inner">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Business theme</a></h3>
                                    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority</p>
                                    <a class="preview" href="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/full/item6.png'|theme }}" rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>         
                    </div><!--/.portfolio-item-->

                    <div class="portfolio-item wordpress html col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="recent-work-wrap">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/recent/item7.png'|theme }}" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="recent-work-inner">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Business theme</a></h3>
                                    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority</p>
                                    <a class="preview" href="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/full/item7.png'|theme }}" rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>          
                    </div><!--/.portfolio-item-->

                    <div class="portfolio-item wordpress html bootstrap col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <div class="recent-work-wrap">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/recent/item8.png'|theme }}" alt="">
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <div class="recent-work-inner">
                                    <h3><a href="#">Business theme</a></h3>
                                    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority</p>
                                    <a class="preview" href="{{ 'assets/images/portfolio/full/item8.png'|theme }}" rel="prettyPhoto"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>          
                    </div><!--/.portfolio-item-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!--/#portfolio-item-->
```

Comment: Precisa carregar script/css **bootstrap** e **jquery-ui** para rodar, e testei esta normal, segue http://www.codeply.com/go/MChm7miyb9

Answer (score -1):

Você usar o Jquery para dar um click no 'botão' que realizar o filtro, exemplo de código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".portfolio-filter.text-center a[data-filter='.html']").click();
 }
```

nesse exemplo estou dando o click no 'botão Photography' e a biblioteca faz o filtro pra você.

para clicar em outro botão você alterar o "data-filter=" de acordo com que está no html do botão do filtro.